# Inserting a control into the visual tree between two objects in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, wpf-controls

I am basically making a popup controller that I can pass a Control to and when popup is activated it will remove the control being "popped up" from its parents children then add it as a child of the popup controller.  I would leave it there however I need events on the object being "popped up" to remain intact and registered.  I tried inserting the popup controller as a child of the original parent. And that might work for routed events however I need plain CLR events to work as well.  For some reason when I remove the child from the parent its events get unwired, at least some do.

People who registered for the events of the control that is now being wrapped need to still get them when they happen.  If I put a breakpoint right before attempting to raise the event the handler is definitely null.

The interesting thing is that if I put it back in its original parent the events immediately begin working again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't break the Visual Tree like this. Your Bindings are not going to work and you will run into all sorts of problems. Why are you doing this?

Comment: because I cant make the object a child of another object without first removing it from its original parent. I am not doing it an a violent way, just doing Children.Remove to remove it.

Comment: My question is about what is your end goal. Why are you not using `DataTemplates` or some other WPF friendlier mechanism. I don't think removing a UI element from the Visual Tree and putting it somewhere else is going to be a good idea.

Comment: Well the end result is that I am moving the item into an Adorner so it will display on top of everything else.  The control in question is a deeply nested custom control and I have a need to blow it up bigger than the containing parent which makes z ordering nearly impossible.